Question about two expressions in Common Lisp - backquote and backtick
Why does 1 work ? why does not 2 work?


(defun exprbis (&rest xs) `(+ (* 2 ,@xs) 1))
EXPRBIS



(defun exprbis (&rest xs) '(+ (* 2 ,@xs) 1))
debugger invoked on a SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1001834103}>: Comma not inside a backquote.....



Thank you Guys!

Isn't the message pretty explicit about that? ,@xs is syntax that only makes sense inside a backtick context; regular 's don't have any way to escape out of them and refer to values instead of just being a literal; the thing that makes a backtick expression different is that you can break out of being a literal and write an expression that substitutes or splices in values.

Thanks @CharlesDuffy for your quick answer. So, let me see if I understand it. The backtick character introduces a quoted expression. Comma after backtick replaces the expression with the value of the that expression. It is similar to the plain quote ('), except that we cannot use a comma after a quoted expression with a straight up quote ‘. Is that correct? I am new at Common Lisp.

See https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm for the official description of how it works in CL.

Oh, and https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dg.htm covers comma outside of a back quoted expression.

Thank @Shawn. I understood something else about backquote. Anyway, I have not still understand the difference between quote with backtick and sraight up quote. Maybe I need to continue working on Common Lisp, I will get there.

'foo is syntactic sugar for (quote foo) which returns foo without further evaluation of it. Backquote is similar but allows selective evaluation of parts indicated by commas.

I found the following one:

`basic is the same as 'basic, that is, (quote basic), for any expression basic that is not a list or a general vector.

This is in https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm

quote and backquote are two very different things.
quote is a special operator in Common Lisp
(quote (a b)) creates a literal constant list (a b). The quote character is an abbreviation. (quote (a b)) can be written as '(a b). quote does not introduce further syntax and so doesn't the quote character. A comma for example has no meaning there and thus will be a syntax error.
The backquote is special syntax of the Lisp reader. Inside the backquoted form there is special syntax for the comma character.
`(a ,b)

means to create a list with two elements: the symbol a and the value of the variable b.
`(a ,@b)

means to create a list with elements: the symbol a and the value, which needs to be a list, of the variable b spliced in.
Summary: the comma has no use inside a quote expression, which is a literal constant.
